# How to find user with MOST rows in table - mysql?

Tags: mysql, count

If you have a column called userID, what query would you use to find the userID with the greatest number of rows in that table?

Thank you

Comment: What output do you expect if 2 users share the same `greatest number of rows`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html), ORDER BY that count DESC and LIMIT the result to the top one:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Filipe, and the other Stackers too!

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, sum(1) as counter 
from TABLE 
group by user_id 
order by 2 desc 
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to get only one user, even if more than one user share the maximum amount of rows:

```
SELECT user_id FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you need to return all matching users:

```
SELECT user_id FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```